# Problems with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I recently created a custom post type called events where i intend to create posts with artistic events in the my area. 
How can I access those posts in the site? because if i go to:
`localhost:####/events` it leads me to the index.php, neither to the cpt archive nor to the cpt post-list 
(with `localhost:####/[ctp post-title]` i get individual posts).

Also, adding categories is being tricky, when i see the post the category isn't listed.

Also, can i get to those post from the Rest-API? i mean from `wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Here the whole functions.php code with taxonomy and the columns setu:

```
// 1. Custom Post Type Registration (Events)

add_action( 'init', 'create_event_postype' );

function create_event_postype() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Agenda', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Agenda', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Agregar nuevo', 'events'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Agregar nuevo evento'),
    'edit_item' => __('Editar evento'),
    'new_item' => __('Nuevo evento'),
    'view_item' => __('Ver evento'),
    'search_items' => __('Buscar eventos'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No se encuentran eventos'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No hay eventos en la basura'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
);

$args = array(
    'label' => __('Agenda'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/cal.png',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "events" ),
    'supports'=> array('title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'editor') ,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array( 'eventcategory', 'post_tag')
);

register_post_type( 'events', $args);

}

// 2. Custom Taxonomy

function create_eventcategory_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove categories' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used categories' ),
);

register_taxonomy('eventcategory','events', array(
    'label' => __('Event Category'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event-category' ),
));
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_eventcategory_taxonomy', 0 );

// 3. Show Columns

add_filter ("manage_edit-events_columns", "events_edit_columns");
add_action ("manage_posts_custom_column", "events_custom_columns");

function events_edit_columns($columns) {

$columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "col_ev_cat" => "Categoría",
    "col_ev_date" => "Fecha",
    "col_ev_times" => "Hora",
    "col_ev_thumb" => "Foto",
    "title" => "Evento",
    "col_ev_desc" => "Descripción",
    );
return $columns;
}

function events_custom_columns($column)
{
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom();
switch ($column)
{
case "col_ev_cat":
    // - show taxonomy terms -
    $eventcats = get_the_terms($post->ID, "eventcategory");
    $eventcats_html = array();
    if ($eventcats) {
    foreach ($eventcats as $eventcat)
    array_push($eventcats_html, $eventcat->name);
    echo implode($eventcats_html, ", ");
    } else {
    _e('None', 'themeforce');;
    }
break;
case "col_ev_date":
    // - show dates -
    $startd = $custom["events_startdate"][0];
    $endd = $custom["events_enddate"][0];
    $startdate = date("F j, Y", $startd);
    $enddate = date("F j, Y", $endd);
    echo $startdate . '<br /><em>' . $enddate . '</em>';
break;
case "col_ev_times":
    // - show times -
    $startt = $custom["events_startdate"][0];
    $endt = $custom["events_enddate"][0];
    $time_format = get_option('time_format');
    $starttime = date($time_format, $startt);
    $endtime = date($time_format, $endt);
    echo $starttime . ' - ' .$endtime;
break;
case "col_ev_thumb":
    // - show thumb -
    $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
    if ($post_image_id) {
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, 'post-thumbnail', false);
    if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
    echo '<img src="';
    echo bloginfo('template_url');
    echo '/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=';
    echo $thumbnail;
    echo '&h=60&w=60&zc=1" alt="" />';
}
break;
case "col_ev_desc";
    the_excerpt();
break;

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function with all arguments?

Comment: there you have it in the post now

Comment: Where is this function located? In a plugin or `functions.php` for the theme?

Comment: it's  in the functions.php

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$args` array, add `'show_in_rest' => true,`. This will enable the REST API integration.

As for your URLs, you need to flush the rewrite rules. Normally you would want to put your custom post type/taxonomy definitions into a plugin so it is separate from your theme since it deals with content creation/structure as opposed to display. In that you could include a call to `flush_rewrite_rules()` using the plugin activation/deactivation hooks.

In your case, just go into the permalink settings and save them if you keep it in your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the 'show_in_rest' property, it worked. 
1- Now i can't access the posts per category, say:  

http://localhost:7878/wp-json/wp/v2/events?categories=1

That works with posts, not with events (my custom post type)
2- Already flushed permalinks. Can you tell me which would be the url that should post all 'events' posts?
3- Which plugin you recommend?

Comment: You have to call it by the slug of the taxonomy that you registered `localhost:7878/wp-json/wp/v2/events?event-category=1`

Comment: You can set the REST API base URL for your custom post type using the `'rest_base'` argument in your `$args` array. If you want it to be events, then add `'rest_base' => 'events',`